# Esc P Brother QL720NW

Tags: php, printing

I'm trying to print from a php script to the thaermal printer in subject with ESC/P language. Everything is ok when i try to normal print text, the problem is that i'm not able to set font size or, generally, formatting options. For example reading the manual i found that if i want to set font size i have to use these codes:

> - [ASCII] ESC X m nL nH
> - [Decimal] 27 88 m nL nH
> - [Hexadecimal] 1B 58 m nL nH

So I've sent comands in this way:

```
fwrite ( $fp, "\x1B \x40" );
        fwrite ( $fp, "\x1B \x58 \x00 \x30 \x80" );
        fwrite ( $fp, $stringToPrint );//"\x72 \x20 \x73 \x69 \x64 \x65");
        fwrite ( $fp, "\x0C" );
```

But it prints simpy the text and number instead of understanding the format options.
Where i'm wrong???

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have the same printer, I can't comment on whether this command will do what you expect, but it does appear that you are including spaces between each byte of the command, which is not correct ESC/P2.

The convention in the [reference](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf) seems to be to include a hex and decimal code for bytes that are meant to be sent, while spacing is just for readability.

A snippet which follows the standard for these commands would be-

```
<?php

// Initialize printer
$fp = fopen("/dev/usb/lp0", "wb+");
fwrite ( $fp, "\x1B\x40" ); // ESC @

// Select font by pitch and point
$m = 0; // No change in pitch
$nL = 48; // Assuming these point options are what you intend?
$nH = 128;
fwrite ( $fp, "\x1B\x58" . chr($m) . chr($nL) . chr($nH)); // ESC X m nL nH

// Print text
$stringToPrint = "Hello\n";
fwrite ( $fp, $stringToPrint );

// Form feed
fwrite ( $fp, "\x0C" ); // FF
```